# Delete google drive folder from trash in Android Application

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I am developing an android application that integrates with google drive.
My android application creates its own google drive folder to hold user documents created by the application.

I want to detect when the user has deleted this application folder and its residing in the google drive TRASH.

When i detect that the folder has been trashed i want to permanently delete it from inside my application.

To detect the folder has been trashed i interrogate its LABELS and find key value pair "trashed"/"true".
I then execute this code to delete it from the trash permanetly

`mService.files().delete(folder.getId());`


However the folder still appears in the google drive trash.

How do i permanently delete a folder from google drive trash?

Comment: Works for me. Is the folder empty? Is it possible to trace the http DELETE to see that it is returning a 204 status? Is there a delay, after which the folder is truly gone?

Comment: No, the folder is not empty! is that the problem then?

Comment: Could be. You'll need to do some of your own testing to be sure. The Drive API layer (sometimes!!!) does a recursive delete of files in a folder. If something goes wrong with that mass deletion, the folder deletion will fail. Out of curiosity, what scope are you using?

Comment: I shall do more testing then. my scope is DriveScopes.DRIVE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
service.files().trash(fileId).execute();
This is for moving file to trash

service.files().untrash(fileId).execute();
for delete file from trash  on server

check this link also :
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/trash
```

Comment: This is not working for my FOLDER, its trashed and untrash has no effect